# Placing divs side by side inside a grid

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

Am trying to place (align) two `divs` (one containing an image, and the other a list) side by side inside a grid,but the result am getting isn't exactly what i want.

This is the result i get:

[image]

when i use this code:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="ui-grid-a" style="border:1px solid black">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><div id="profile_photo"><img id="avatar" src="images/Free.jpg" width="400" height="400"></div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#">Name name</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Occupation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, the list is positioned on the far right corner. I want it to start where the border of the image ends. What changes do i need to make to this? Is it even possible using this attempt?

*Update:* This is the only css code am using (yes, i know it's almost nothing)

```
.ui-block-a,
.ui-block-b,
.ui-block-c
{
background-color: lightgray;
border: 1px solid black;
height: 100px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
padding: 30px;
 }
```

Comment: we are going to need your CSS code to answer corectly.

Comment: @JamesDavies kindly convert your answer to a comment to prevent a downvote apocalypse.I just updated the question to include my CSS.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/Vrwqx/

Comment: Yes,but i tried the code in my application with no changes.

Comment: there must be some other styles conflicting with the float property I added

Comment: I think so too.I am using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />` in my html.I think that's where the problem is.

Comment: There's your problem. jQuery mobile is applying a 50% width to each of those ui-blocks. You either need to override that CSS or not use jQuery mobile CSS. OR put the list inside the same ui-block as the image.

Comment: @OjonugwaOchalifu Check out my answer for a better solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery Mobile is applying 50% width to ui-grid-a & ui-grid-b, Because of that the entire width is divided into two sections of equal width.

```
.ui-grid-a > .ui-block-a, .ui-grid-a > .ui-block-b {
   width: 50%;
}
```

As a result of that,  you right div with menu is looking to be right aligned.

If you want to override that, then add

```
float: left;  width: auto !important;
```

to your css as follows:

```
.ui-block-a,
.ui-block-b,
.ui-block-c
{
background-color: lightgray;
border: 1px solid black;
height: 500px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
padding: 30px;
float: left;
width: auto !important;
 }
```

Now your image and div will be properly aligned

[image]

**[JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/pezuy/1/edit)**

But doing this may affect the css in other places where you will be using .ui-grid-* blocks.

Better instead of wrapping the content inside those grid blocks, wrap them inside a custom div and add your CSS which will be specific to your case

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="ui-grid-a" style="border:1px solid black">
        <div class="blockdiv">
          <div id="profile_photo"><img id="avatar" src="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/images-photo.jpg" width="400" ></div></div>
        <div class="blockdiv">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#">Name name</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Occupation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .blockdiv {
       width: auto !important;
       float: left;
       padding-top: 10px;
       margin-right: 20px !important;
    }
```

[image]

**[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/warakahu/1/edit)**

Comment: Your edit worked just the way i wanted it to.**BUT** (don't worry you'll get your bounty) when i reduce the width of the image to say 80%, they (image and listview) become separated again.Is there a way around this?

Comment: use this as your blockdiv css .blockdiv {
 width: auto !important;
float: left;
padding-top: 10px;
margin-right: 10px !important;
}

Comment: DOn't specify % in image width anymore.. i have updated answer, use the latest code. Here is the demo http://jsbin.com/warakahu/1/edit

Comment: Man i still can't get it to work this way in mine.I think it's because am using `jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js` but the working example you gave uses `jquery.mobile-1.1.2.min.js`

Comment: I have updated the jquery-mobile version. here is demo http://jsbin.com/warakahu/3/edit update margin-right to 20px as in that css

Comment: Now it works.I can now move on with my life.Hehehe.Thanks man.I will award you your bounty in 11hrs.

Comment: Haha great to hear.. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

This should get you on the right track, basically you just need to override the jQuery mobile CSS that is applying a width to those blocks of content:

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="ui-grid-a" style="border:1px solid black">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <div id="profile_photo">
                <img id="avatar" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/400/400" width="400" height="400" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#">Name name</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Occupation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ui-block-a, .ui-block-b, .ui-block-c {
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ui-grid-a>.ui-block-a {
    width:400px;
}
img {
    float:left
}
li {
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VL2U2/)

Comment: I just tried this but am still getting the same result.This is what i did, i created a new css file and copied the css into it, i then added the link to the file `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/custom-styles">` in html.

Comment: There needs to be a ".css" at the end of the href. You can see in my JSFiddle that it does work.

Comment: Oh.Well, i added it and only the background color changed.Sigh.